# Free UML tool, ideally for .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++, tool-uml

Could anyone suggest an UML tool which you have used and would like to recommend (please provide pros and cons of the tool you recommend, if possible), that meets the following requirements:

1) Free, and comply with standards

2) Ideally for .NET

Please note that the UML in Visual studio Pro is not good enough, VS Ultimate is not considered.

Below is a list on google
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend [Software Ideas Modeler](http://www.softwareideas.net/).

- UML
- Data Flow Diagram
- Flowchart
- Robustness Diagram
- CRC
- Entity-Relationship-Diagram

It can create models out of C# and VB.NET Code. It can also generate code from models for a lot of languages, including C#, C++ and VB.NET. It's free for non-commercial use.

Comment: But... it's not free (that's the primary request)

Answer (score 2):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) can generate C# code, I've haven't used it integrated with Visual Studio but as a standalone product.

Comment: staruml is nice, but dead - yet it ist too dumb to handle generics/templates when reverse engineering code

Answer (score 0):

rise
uml

test the program UML rise :D

Comment: Could you elaborate why you like it?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend LightSpeed by Mindscape.co.nz.If your model is under 8 tables its free otherwise its an affordable price given its a code generator and dB sync tool as well.